# How to do this query to select N rows with highest numbers ordered by col

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

Lets say  I have a table that has three columns: ID, Name and Users.

I want to select the 3 rows with the highest number of users and I wanted the rows to be ordered by the Name Ascending. How can I Achieve that?

I used

```
select Name from TABLE where  ID IN (select ID from Tablesorder by  Users desc  limit 3)
```

But IN/ANY are not supported. Any other ways?
Thanks

Comment: which version of SQL?

Comment: which database are you using

Comment: I meant to say mysql.. Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When subqueries are allowed, you could use this.
It fetches the 3 records with highest value for column users. These 3 results will be ordered in the outer query.

```
select Name from 
(
    select Name 
    from Tables 
    order by  Users desc  
    limit 3
) as temp
ORDER BY Name ASC
```

Comment: Need not to write ASC. Its default case of ORDER BY

Comment: No need to, but it would be more clear to the OP though.

Answer (score 1):

In Mysql :

```
SELECT id, name, users
FROM (SELECT id,name,users FROM tablename ORDER BY users DESC LIMIT 3) as a
ORDER BY name;
```

In Sql server

```
SELECT id, name, users
FROM (SELECT TOP 3 id,name,users FROM tablename ORDER BY users DESC ) as a
ORDER BY name;
```

In Oracle

```
SELECT id, name, users
FROM (SELECT id,name,users FROM tablename ORDER BY users DESC ) as a
WHERE ROWNUM<=3
ORDER BY name;
```

Comment: The OP's example query contains 'LIMIT 3'. I think the Oracle and SqlServer examples are not necessary.